# Applying the inclusion exclusion principle to count permutations with forbidden subsequences

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I have problem with this: 
How many permutations of the letters A,B,D,E,I,K,M,N,R,U,Z are there so that none of the words: **ARZEN, DRAK, DUM, DURAZ** are subsequences of the permutation. This means it should be impossible to make these words by leaving out letters from the permutation, but leaving the remaining ones in order.

This task is about Inclusion-exclusion principle, but I can't understand.

Can anyone explain me how to solve this task? thanks

edit:I have understood the complexity of this question just now. A real task also describe, that: sequence can't have any of words {ARZEN,DRAK,DUM,DURAZ}. That means that sequence "**A** B D **R** K **Z** M **E** **N** U I" also should not be counted, because the bold letters form the forbidden word **ARZEN**.
Sequence must have 11 letters.

Comment: What does "also we delete some letters" mean? Just that some of the $26$ letters of the alphabet do not occur in the given list (which is quite obvious)? Or does is mean that letters already used "are deleted from the stock" so that they cannot be used again? Please be clear what you are asking.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify what to me seemed the intended meaning, using standard terminology ("permutation" implies no letters appears more than once, "subsequence" means the remaining letters do not have to be consecutive, as they would for a "subword"). If I distorted the meaning of the question, please correct it again.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote the set of permutations with subsequence $s$ by $B_s$. The result is
$$11! - \left(|B_{ARZEN}| + |B_{DRAK}| + \ldots\right) + \left(|B_{ARZEN}\cap B_{DRAK}|+\ldots\right) - \left(|B_{ARZEN}\cap B_{DRAK}\cap B_{DUM}|+\ldots\right) + |B_{ARZEN}\cap B_{DRAK}\cap B_{DUM}\cap B_{DURAZ}|. $$

For example:
$|B_{ARZEN}|= 6\cdot7\cdots11=\frac{11!}{5!},$ (we have $6$ possibilities for inserting one letter to the word $ARZEN$, $7$ possibilities for second letter, etc.

$|B_{ARZEN}\cap B_{DRAK}|=0$ because of letters $R$ and $A$,

$|B_{DURAZ}\cap B_{DUM}|=4\cdot 7\cdot8\cdots11.$ ($4$ possibilities for inserting $M$ to $DURAZ$, etc.)

Comment: And for DUM,DURAZ and DRAK together is it |BDUM∩BDURAZ∩BDRAK|= 4⋅3⋅2⋅8⋅....⋅11?

Comment: Starting with $DURAZ$, you have 2 places for the letter $K$ and then 5 places for $M$. The result is $2 \cdot5 \cdot 8 \cdots 11$. Could you explain your method?

Comment: I have 2 places for K,M and Z.

Comment: I don't get it. What is your starting point? Which letter do you insert first?

Comment: First letter-D, Second letter- U, 3th- M or R, 4th -A, 5th-Z or K,  6th- Z or K